# How to use pandas read_csv() to read a file containing more than just one table?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to extract all information from example.csv. The file has three parts of information and is formatted as below:

```
Date,2017/07/15,Time,20:00,
ColA, ColB, ColC,
1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6,
ColD, ColE
7, 8,
```

I use `df=pd.read_csv('example.csv', header=None)` to read all the information from the csv, but I'm only getting an error message. My goal is to have a table like:

```
Date        Time ColA_1  ColB_1  ColC_1  ColA_2  ColB_2  ColC_2 ColD  ColE  
2017/07/15  20:00  1       2       3        4       5      6     7     8
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is every file like the above _example.csv_ going to be in the same formatting or will that depend on the file?

Comment: At what point in the csv does the new table start?

Comment: Consider fixing the source of that file instead of a data wrangling headache in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting wishes are very specific so I don't really see anything simpler than the following:

```
# Load this using open from the csv    
s = "Date,2017/07/15,Time,20:00\nColA, ColB, ColC\n1, 2, 3\n4, 5, 6\nColD, ColE\n7, 8" 
s = s.replace(" ", "")

s_arr = s.split('\n')
s_arr = [x.split(',') for x in s_arr]
columns = [s_arr[0][0], s_arr[0][2]] + s_arr[1][0:3] + s_arr[4][0:2]
row = [s_arr[0][1], s_arr[0][3],[s_arr[2][0],s_arr[3][0]],[s_arr[2][1],s_arr[3][1]],[s_arr[2][2],s_arr[3][2]]] + s_arr[5][0:2]
```

This gives:

```
columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC', 'ColD', 'ColE']
row = ['2017/07/15', '20:00', ['1', '4'], ['2', '5'], ['3', '6'], '7', '8']
```

The lists can be used to initialize your pandas table. Depending on how the rows are organized in the csv you may need to split it another level (e.g. if there is two white lines between rows, then you can use `split('\n\n')`).